# Action interface error 'Property does not exist on type'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a `type` that can take the structure of 3 interfaces, but when using a property of 2 of those 3 interfaces, I get an error.

The action should have a `token` property when it takes the structure of `IAuthSuccessAction` interface, and an `error` property when it takes the structure of `IAuthFailAction` interface.

What do I miss?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**After I try to apply a given suggestion from @Baka:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: why you are merging type with interface ?

Comment: @programoholic so I can set ```action``` inside the reducer as AuthAction, which would respect one of those 3 interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `IBasicAction` from `AuthAction` union and add unique `type` fields to `IAuthFailAction` and `IAuthSuccessAction` (reuse values from `actionTypes`) like this:

```
interface IAuthFailAction extends IBasicAction {
    type: 'fail';
    error: object;
}

interface IAuthSuccessAction extends IBasicAction {
    type: 'success';
    token: string;
}

type AuthAction = IAuthFailAction | IAuthSuccessAction;
```

This way you'll end up with [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) and TS will be able to determent what property is available based on `type` field

If `actionTypes` is defined as literal object, consider using [`const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)
assertion or switch to [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). Also you need to use [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) operator when referencing type of property of your literal object, e.g.

```
const actionTypes = {
  ACTION: 'ACTION',
} as const

interface ISomeAction {
  type: typeof actionTypes.ACTION
}

const action: ISomeAction = {
  type: 'ACTION'
}
```

Example with `enum`:

```
enum actionTypes {
  ACTION = 'ACTION'
}

interface ISomeAction {
  type: actionTypes.ACTION
}

const action: ISomeAction = {
  type: actionTypes.ACTION
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the string stored inside ```actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL``` for some reason. More details inside the last 2 pics of the post

Comment: @gusti Edited my answer with examples about how you can reuse properties of `actionTypes`